# How to create a Tilemap light in Unity's new 2D light system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2D platformer game and I wish to use the new Unity 2D lighting system. I have a tilemap with the start and end tiles (and perhaps other things), and I want them lit up. How do I light up every tile in a specific Tilemap?

I tried using a Global 2D light on the tilemap.

The problem with that is that it lights up everything in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to apply materials that can interact properly with the 2D lights placed in your scene here is a [link](https://forum.unity.com/threads/2d-lighting-not-working-on-tilemap.718394/) to a similar question on the unity forum that may be of use to you.

Comment: I don't need help on how to light up the tilemap, I just want there to be a specific light on only one tilemap (I have multiple tilemaps in my scene.)